# applying a function to a pair of elements in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, iterator

I have a list of strings like this:

```
sample = ["apple and apple and more apples", 
                  "apple, mangos and more apples", 
                  "pink is the new black or is it?",
                  "pink and pink with more red and black",
                  "apples are red and strawberry is marron/dark-pink"]
```

I would like to do fuzzy matching on these strings in order, something like  `fuzzy(sample[0], sample[1])`, `fuzzy(sample[1], sample[2])`, `fuzzy(sample[2], sample[3])`, `fuzzy(sample[3], sample[4])`

and to do this I wrote something like this:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

for i,j in zip(*[iter(sample)]*2):
    print(fuzz.QRatio(i, j))
```

but what this does is, it only produces `fuzzy(sample[0], sample[1])` and `fuzzy(sample[2], sample[3])` how to I get the output for the other two pairs of strings(i.e...`fuzzy(sample[1], sample[2])`, `fuzzy(sample[3], sample[4])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sample[:-1]` and `sample[1:]` instead will do.

```
print(list(map(fuzz.QRatio, sample[:-1], sample[1:])))
```